# How to manage memory leaks from unused atoms in Recoil.js atomFamily?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I'm using Recoil.js in my project, where I dynamically generate atoms using `atomFamily`.

In my use case, I need to load a large number of items, each with a UUID and additional data. I'm using the UUIDs as the parameter for the atoms. I need to create my own management method for these items and remove the unnecessary items.

Recoil does offer some mechanisms, such as `useResetRecoilState`, but it doesn't seem to be a good method for managing a large number of atoms in atomFamily, because hooks can't be used inside loops.

Jotai offers a `remove` function as part of its family utility (see https://jotai.org/docs/utilities/family). Does Recoil offer a similar functionality or how can I achieve the equivalent in Recoil?